# Prove: $m(A)=0 \iff m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Prove: $m(A)=0 \iff m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B)$ for all $B\subset \mathbb{R}$
>
> Where $m^*$ is an outer measure and $m$ is lebesgue measure

$\to:$
$$ m^*(A\cup B)\leq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$$ by subadditivity
$$m(A)=m^*(A)=0$$
so $$m^*(A\cup B)\leq m^*(B)$$
now
$$B\subseteq A\cup B$$
so $$m^*(B)\leq m^*(A\cup B)$$
by monotonic of the outer measure
so $$m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B)$$

$\leftarrow:$

We know that $0\leq m^*(A)$ by definition, how can I show that $m^*(A)\leq 0$? Can I conclude that if $m^*(A)=0$ then $m(A)=0$?

Comment: The statement is not clear. What is $B$ ?

Comment: For $B=A$, we have $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B)$, but in general $m(A)\ne 0$

Comment: What are your assumptions about $A$? Are you assuming $A$ is measurable, or is that part of the conclusion on the left side of the if and only if?

Comment: @CarlMummert the only assumption is that $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ which I forget to write at first.

Answer (score 3):

If the hypothesis is a for fixed $B$ we cannot conclude that $m(A)=0$, For example $m^{*}(A\cup B)=m^{*}(B)$ holds with $B =\mathbb R$. If this holds for all $B$ we can take $B=\emptyset $ to get $m^{*}(A)=0$ and hence $m(A)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, it is $B\subset \mathbb{R}$